# login to a virtualized server?

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtual-machines

I have installed a virtualized debain 5 with VMware Player on Windows 7.

Can I login with ssh to my virtualized server from my Windows?

(sorry couldn't explain it better :D )

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have configured your network settings correctly in VMWare player to allow access from the host, then yes you should be able to SSH into the guest.

Comment: HMM which ip address should i use to login with?

Comment: @yes123 - the address assigned to the virtual debian 5 guest. You have to understand that as clever as virtualisation is, it doesn't do anything magical to networking; each machine running in a virtual machine needs an IP address (either a 'real' one from/on your LAN, or I think it can self assign an IP and NAT through your host) and you communicate with this box much like you would any other device on your network.